# How can I specify the path to libpcap when configuring/making/installing?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, libraries, compile

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.1 and am trying to get packet capturing working for my Bluetooth dongle using `hcidump`.

From what I've read, libpcap must be compiled to enable Bluetooth sniffing and given that hcidump isn't finding a single packet, I'm guessing the version Ubuntu has installed for me isn't compiled with bluetooth support.

So I downloaded a newer version of libpcap and installed the bluez header files. Configured libpcap and it gave a "Yes" for bluetooth support. It is now installed and sitting in `/usr/local/lib/`.

Now I'm trying to compile hcidump to use this lib rather than the system default but I can't figure out how...

I've read that GCC can be passed the `-lpcap` flag to set the path but I haven't figured out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the `libpcap` package and it appears that all you need to do to get Bluetooth support is to compile it with bluetooth development files installed. That is, install the [libbluetooth-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libbluetooth-dev) [image: Install libbluetooth-dev] package, then recompile `libpcap`:

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev build-essential fakeroot
sudo apt-get build-dep libpcap
apt-get source libpcap
cd libpcap-*
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -nc -us -uc
sudo dpkg -iGO ../*.deb
```

(Better, before the `dpkg-buildpackage` step, add a version to `debian/control` so that your package bears a version number that's different from the official package, such as 1.0.0-6bloo1.)

Then try the `hcidump` executable from the [bluez-hcidump](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bluez-hcidump) [image: Install bluez-hcidump].

If you do need to recompile `hcidump` and pass it a custom include file path (and probably a custom library file path as well), the way with most programs that have a `configure` script is to run

```
CFLAGS='-I /path/to/dependency/include' LDFLAGS='-L /path/to/dependency/lib' ./configure …
```

`/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` are usually included in the default search, though.